# Sharing Chrome Dev Tools Coverage report with developer and report

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, code-coverage

We have projects based on javascript (React, veu). Using chrome DevTools are trying to remove unused Code and also check coverage during our manual testing.

Puppeteer and Istanbul was good combination to generate report for Automation testing, but not finding solution where in Manual testing is done and from different user and share it to developer for  analysis and fix unused code. Need suggestions/inputs:

1. How can a developer import the code coverage JSON file created by tester and use it?
2. Can we combine Coverage JSON generated by different tester? All tester may not cover same flow, to get correct data on coverage we would need to combine JSON from different testers

Or as an Alternative can Puppeteer made to capture manual action and generate report?